# Backgroundcolor on ListView Items

Tags: android, listview, background-color

my problem:

```
ring5Views[i]
                .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View arg1, int position, long arg3) {


            arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#444444"));

                    }

                });
```

if I click on one Item (child) every second item (%2) will change its bg color.
Why ?

The hole thing I want is a list with items and different colors for each but getChild dont solve the prob because NULL every time. And getItem dont help because it only gives back the value (string)

This is how it should work...

```
for(int i=0; i<oneList;i++)
        {
            oneList.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.blue);
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the **ArrayAdapter** and override the **getView** method. And inside the getView method based on the condition you can change the color

you can see this [Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) for reference